# Node is not returning values for successful stored procedure

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

Are you still dealing with this problem?

```
CALL eveql.sp_matFinder('ishkur');
```

Returns successfully within DBeaver and returns 15 rows for me.
I've followed this syntax in node.js for the call.

```
connection.query('CALL eveql.sp_matFinder(?);', [itemName], function(err, rows){
       if(err) throw err;
       console.log(rows);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
});
```

.query( is returning successfully, however I receive an empty array where my results should be.

```
[ **[]**,
OkPacket {
fieldCount: 0,
affectedRows: 0,
insertId: 0,
serverStatus: 34,
warningCount: 0,
message: '',
protocol41: true,
changedRows: 0 } ]
Data :  [[],{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":34,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}]
```

So I'm also at a loss. It could be versioning issues with mysql against node version.

Comment: Instead of calling a stored procedure, have you tried issuing plain old SELECT statement? That might help ensure your JavaScript code is working.

Comment: I will be able to test this theory later today. We'll see if it is helpful.

Comment: Look at this article and using IN/OUT parameters. Note they syntax on the CALL statement. https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

Comment: I've referenced that site, still the same problems. I have done a direct call and now I get 15 rows of "undefined". But the cool thing is that the actual query with the same input in dbeaver retrieves 15 rows.

Comment: So you were right. Using a select statement gave me what I was looking for. I guess there's some other way to perform stored procedure calls within node.

Comment: @Element.CR Did you figure out any other way to get the stored procedure results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per mysql [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines-syntax.html)

> A procedure is invoked using a CALL statement (see Section 13.2.1,
>   “CALL Syntax”), and can only pass back values using output variables.
>   A function can be called from inside a statement just like any other
>   function (that is, by invoking the function's name), and can return a
>   scalar value.

Either use a function to return the result set or use an OUT parameter to return a scalar value.